# In a dual monitor setup, how to find which monitor a given window is on?

Tags: debian, multiple-monitors, console, window-manager

I am writing a python script to resize and organize windows, just like the `grid` plugin does in `compiz-fusion`(except that I am on *Debian Wheezy*).

I am using `xrandr` and `wmctrl` to get the resolutions of my two screens and compute custom sizes for windows (split horizontally, vertically, etc...):

- `xrandr` tells me how many screen I have and their resolutions
- `wmctrl` gives me original sizes of windows and their location (on which workspace they are displayed)

Unfortunately my 2 screens don't have the same resolution at all, so the only information I am missing is: **on which screen the windows is currently displayed** so that I can compute new sizes that fit gracefully in this screen.

Is there any command/program that could get this info ?

Comment: FWIW I had a look at `xdotool` but unfortunately it is not aware of the dual screen setup, all it can see is a single *big* screen. Indeed `xdotool getmouselocation` always displays `screen:0` even if I move my mouse around both screen...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so looking at this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/110106), it seems that **there is no way** of doing this *directly* (and my comment about `xdotool` tends to confirm that), all we can do is find a hacky solution.

I am thinking about this:

- Get the window geometry via `wmctrl` (coordinates of the window i.e. its top left corner)
- Compare it with screen resolutions and deduce on which screen it is displayed

I'm still open to alternatives solution though :)